# How can I send emails in background in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

## Background

I found [this](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Send-Emails-In-The-Background-With-Gmail.htm) that suggests the following:

[image: Instructions to send in background]

I went to look for this setting but cannot find it:

[image: Gmail labs settings]

## Question

Is there an alternative way to send emails in the background in Gmail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that labs entry was either removed or incorporated into gmail.

This is from the [link](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Send-Emails-In-The-Background-With-Gmail.htm) you provided in your question:

> Note that background sending is currently the default (and only)
>   option in Gmail. You need not enable or do anything to have Gmail send
>   in the background.

also note the blog entry was updated on September 16 2016.

Comment: Interesting! It doesn't work for me. Gmail waits until my attachments are uploaded.